# JQUERY IF/ ELSE no syntax error just not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a box move -340 px to the left when the page hits 1024px screen width and then when you open the browser window wider it goes back to it's original state.  I used jslint and corrected the syntax, but nothing is happening in the code to make it react, Any help would be much appreciated, maybe I overlooked something or my thought process may be slightly off. THANKS!

```
function move() {
var box =-340;
var pagewidth = $('body').width();

if (pagewidth>1024) {
box=pagewidth-box;
box=box+'px right';
}else {
box=pagewidth-box;
box=box+'px left';

}
$('#vt_nice_slideshow180').css('margin-left', box );

}

$(document).ready(function(){
move();
$(window).resize(move);

});
```

Comment: You should consider using CSS responsive design rather then reinventing the wheel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx

Comment: The lines like `box=box+'px right';` are invalid. Since `box` is numeric you're trying to set the left margin to something like `100px right` which is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

change your call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    move();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    move();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

j08691's answer is the same I confirmed while they were posting it...

The lines

```
box=box+'px right';
```

and

```
box=box+'px left';
```

are invalid. Since box is numeric you're trying to set the left margin to something like '100px right' which is invalid css.

Comment: I need to drag that box past the browser window when it is resized. So basically it is a big image and for this site it is called for this image to be slid over past the window to hide part of the image.  With just the if statement it works but it won't resize back to the orignal state unless the browser is refreshed.  this site is not meant to be responsive.

Comment: whether the if statement works or not by itself you still are using invalid css.

Comment: and nothing I do does cause the if statement to work by itself...so again invalid css!

Answer (score 0):

a.you are using invalid CSS. the `margin` property doesn't accept right or left as **values**.
if you want to manipulate the **key**, add the right or left there.

b. You are assigning a negative value to `box`, and then again subtract it from `pagewidth`, so you actually end up adding (--=+)

c. No need to add `px`. This is JQuery's default, so you can pass an integer.

d. Better to approach it with CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: wow, yea I am retarded it's cool, you know sometimes when you try to overthink things you just overlook the obvious. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function move() {
    var pagewidth = $('body').width();
    var box = -340;
    box = pagewidth - box;
    if (pagewidth > 1024) {
       $('#vt_nice_slideshow180').css('margin-left', box + +'px right');
    }else{ 
       $('#vt_nice_slideshow180').css('margin-left', box + 'px left');
    }
}
```

Greetings.